# Castle Windsor Weak Typed Factory

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

In a very very limited number of scenarios, I need to go from an unknown Type (at compile time) to an instance of the object registered for that type.

For the most part, I use typed factories and I know the type I want to resolve at compile time...so I inject a `Func<IMyType>` into a constructor

...but in these limited number of scenarios, in order to avoid a direct call to the container (and thus having to reference Windsor from the library, which is an anti-pattern I'd like to avoid), I need to inject a `Func<Type,object>`...which I want to internally container.Resolve(type) for the Type parameter of the Func.

Does anyone have some suggestions on the easiest/most straightforward way of setting this up?

I tried the following, but with this setup, I end up bypassing the regular TypedFactoryFacility altogether which is definitely not what I want:

```
Kernel.Register(Component.For(typeof (Func<Type, object>)).LifeStyle.Singleton.UsingFactoryMethod(
                    (kernel, componentModel, creationContext) => 
                        kernel.Resolve(/* not sure what to put here... */)));
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy if you remember that you can register delegates in Windsor as normal components:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Func<Type,object>>()
   .Instance(t=>container.Resolve(t)));
```

You can also do that via typed factory (which is the recommended approach if you plan to resolve transient components via this factory, as typed factory gives you scoping) and a [custom selector](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx#Custom_codeITypedFactoryComponentSelectorcodes_15).

```
    container.Register(
         Component.For<YourSelector>(),
         Component.For<Func<Type,object>>().Lifestyle.Transient
             .AsFactory(x=>x.SelectedWith<YourSelector>());
```

Comment: I decided to inject an instance of a simple IServiceProvider that takes a Func<Type,object>. Any concerns there?

Comment: How is that different from using the function directly? Any concerns relate to lifetime. Think about when the objects you pull will be released and if you don't introduce memory leaks. That's all

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the common service locator for this http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/, which I think Ayende wrote the support for Castle Windsor for http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2008/10/02/the-common-service-locator-library.aspx. It basically provides a way of resolving a dependency without having a dependency on the particular container (e.g. Windsor/Ninject etc). You do end up with a dependency on the common service locator at the level you are resolving for but at least you can swap out e.g. Windsor to Ninject at the application level so it can be used in different projects.

To initialize:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => { return new WindsorServiceLocator(_container); });
```

where _container is your IWindsorContainer, and then to resolve dependencies:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyType>();
```

or

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<MyType>();
```

Comment: I don't really want to add another dll dependency to my projects...and using the Service Locator is generally considered a bad idea since it doesn't demonstrate expressiveness in component use (IMHO).